# Laravel - Call Parameter from Request

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to call 'status_id' = 0 from the picture below

[image]

Controller:

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
 if ($request == "0"){
        return $this->index();
    } else {
        return "2";
}
```

This is how I try to call the status id, I know it's wrong, anyone can enlighten me how can i call status id so it can return to index. Now it return to 2

Comment: simple `$request->status_id`

Comment: Wah, thank you! I don't know it just this simple.

Comment: You can get any params from `$request` using `$request->param_name_you_want`.